# FOSUserBundle in Symfony 2 - Returns NULL when trying to find existing user

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, fosuserbundle

FOSUserBundle, according to documentation, fails to retrieve existing user that It created a second ago and returns NULL.

config.yml for fos_user:

```
fos_user:
db_driver: mongodb
firewall_name: main
user_class: SignalsPlatform\SpotApiBundle\Document\User
use_listener: false
```

User model (default):

```
<?php namespace SignalsPlatform\SpotApiBundle\Document;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Document(
 *  db="signals",
 *  collection="User"
 * )
 */
class User extends BaseUser {
    /**
    * @MongoDB\Id(strategy="auto")
    */
    protected $id;
}
```

RegisterController:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/user/create", name="user_create")
 * @param Request $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    /** @var \FOS\UserBundle\Doctrine\UserManager $userManager */
    $userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');

    $foundUser = $userManager->findUserByEmail($request->request->getAlpha('email'));
    var_dump($foundUser); // returns NULL
```

MongoDB find result:

```
> use signals
switched to db signals
```

> db.User.find({email:'picuvypoxe@gmail.com'})

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54b3aba3d700e9ab198b4568"), "usernameCanonical" : "lojixyc", "email" : "picuvypoxe@gmail.com", "emailCanonical" : "picuvypoxe@gmail.com", "enabled" : true, "salt" : "l4vsg8j59u884w8w0okwo0o4ogscssw", "password" : BinData(5,"UGEkJHcwcmQh"), "locked" : false, "expired" : false, "roles" : [ ], "credentialsExpired" : false, "firstName" : "Alexis", "lastName" : "Lancaster", "country" : "IL", "phone" : "(+972) 695898", "birthDate" : "8-8-1930", "userName" : "lojixyc", "currency" : "USD", "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-01-12T11:10:27Z") }
```

If any information is missing - let me know. This default code snippets suppose to find the user.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like

> $request->request->getAlpha('email')

Was stripping off email special characters, replacing with

> $request->request->get('email')

Fixed the issue.